# Loop is ending for clicking elements within list

Tags: python, selenium

My problem is that
1st part:
I have to fetch all the href values dynamically

2nd part:
After fetching I need to click on href value which are required(ex:i mean if dynamically I fetch 20 href value in that only 8 I need to click )

And catch is that the href value keeps on changing (1st part I know how to do but 2 part I am not sure how to implement)

```
    hamburgerDrop = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//tr[@data-category-id='15']/td[3]")
    elements = hamburgerDrop.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,"a")
    for link in elements:
        if link.get_attribute('href'):
            link.click()
            print("the element found")
            driver.back()
            time.sleep(4)
            break
    else:
        print("element is not found")
```

From the above code which I have written I am able to click only one href value if I want to click on the second I cant do it

for example:( thing is out of 20 href value i want to click only 8 )
So i wrote a code like this

```
    def find_products(self):
    elements = self.captureLinks(self.category_container,"xpath","a,li,div")
    for link in elements:
        if link.get_attribute('href') = 'https://example.com,/c/announcements' :
            link.click()
            self.log.info("The products link is  found")
            time.sleep(3)

    else:
        self.log.info("The products link is not found")
    self.back()
    time.sleep(5)
```

when my manager reviewed this code ,they told me with out comparing with href value it should click on the respective link .

```
def find_products(self):
    elements = self.captureLinks(self.category_container,"xpath","a,li,div")
    for link in elements:
        if "announcements" in link.get_attribute('href') :
            link.click()
            self.log.info("The products link is  found")
            time.sleep(3)

    else:
        self.log.info("The products link is not found")
    self.back()
    time.sleep(5)
    return elements
```

so i changed the code like this but when i executed i am getting the error
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Comment: What do you think `break` does?

Comment: Please formulate the title in form of a question that describes the problem. After all, which question here _doesn't_ need a solution?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your loop is being ended with `break`. Remove this and the loop should continue